# How do I get the same environment for a child thread in TCL?

Tags: multithreading, tcl, environment

I am using multi thread in TCL. I am creating a thread using thread extension. I then send some commands to the thread.
I also use user defined some procedures in various files.
My question: how do I make the global variables from the main thread available to the child thread, WITHOUT passing as arguments or using Thread shared variables ?

I don't know how many of those variables would be there, and hence would like to import them all

I tried looking up environment share but the only references I get are that the environment VARIABLES are already shared. I need the whole system to be available to the child thread.

Regarding the libraries, I am able to simply source them.

sample code

```
global var1

thread::create {
source <library files >(has dummyProc definition)
<execute some statements>
}

thread::send "dummyProc arg1 arg2...argN" result
```

My problem: dummyProc uses variables available in the main thread (e.g. var1), while NOT USING either TSV or pass them as arguments, since there would be a whole set of those global variables.

Comment: Please put what you're trying to do in your original question. It's difficult to read code like that.

Comment: This sounds a bit like you try to force the common 'shared state' threading concept onto Tcl's 'message passing' style threads, which is a bad match. While it might be possible to do what you want with the help of variable traces and other tricks (for example by renaming 'set' and replacing it with a special version that queries another thread for any asked for variables), it probably is a bad idea. Why do you need to allow access to the whole environment in a thread?

Answer (score 1):

Tcl's thread support code is designed around the principle that you don't do this; it's a *very* deep assumption. Each thread has its own interpreters; the only shared state is that which you explicitly create via the [tsv](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/ThreadCmd/tsv.htm) sub-package (that's part of the 8.6 documentation tree, but it's not significantly different in earlier versions). By far the simplest way of implementing a thread is to put its definition code in a (normal!) `.tcl` script file and to just pass in the instructions to `source` it when creating the thread, along with any small bits of extra information that you need to configure to make it be a particular thread doing a particular task.

The plus side of this? Tcl's implementation has far fewer big global locks than comparable languages. (It was contributed originally by some people who were writing production-grade commercial web servers in almost-pure Tcl.)

---

That said, if you really want to clone an interpreter, it's not too hard to do at least some of it. Packages can be loaded in the other interpreter, namespaces are usually pretty easy to clone (with the exception of those that are children of `::oo` for various complex reasons), procedures can be copied easily (`info body`, `info args` and `info default` are the required tools for that) as can global/namespace variables (especially if you don't worry about traces or keeping the variables synchronized).

Other things are much trickier. Open channels? Very hard to clone, often impossible. Object graphs for something like TclOO? Well, easier than channels! Tk widgets? Don't try; lots of experience in other languages indicates that multi-threaded GUIs are actually brain-bending.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I have now edited the original question, included the code, hopefully for better understanding.

However, I have now moved on to a different approach to my original problem, switched the foreground and background processes, and the new commands to be sent to child thread require minimal variables and overhead. However I am stuck on a different problem now, "Expect" in the child thread crashes tclsh, so does `package require Expect`, while it works the main thread. Any help in that regard would be appreciated! I will post it as a separate question as well. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, this is the question, already on stackoverflow, and you have already answered on it. Is there any solution to it now?
I am using 8.5.x on windows machines.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123195/in-tcl-seg-faults-from-multiple-threads-requiring-expect

Comment: That's good to know. How can I "send" a variable with a lot of content, including line breaks, quotations marks and the likes to a thread? I always get into trouble (quoting hell)? Is there an easy way of cloning a variable into a thread?